# Laravel: Can't install Sentry

Tags: laravel

I tried to install Sentry 2 with composer. I used the composer manuel from the sentry site,
but i got always a serviceprovider exception:

"Class 'Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider' not found"

Is there an another way or i did something wrong?

Comment: Did you try to run `composer update` and/or `composer --dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Yes, but i got the same error.

And i see... It is not only a problem with sentry, i can't install intervention (image manipulation). Always the same error, that composer didn't find the ServiceProvider.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely on the [[Sentry website installer instructions for laravel 4](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4)],

step one states that you need to add `"cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*"` to your `composer.json`,
but it also specifically states that it ***requires you to run*** `php composer.phar update` ***from the command line***

**Note** that you should run `php composer.phar update` **BEFORE** you add the entries for the `app/config/app.php` *(before proceeding to steps 2 and above)*

@Todd Isaacs's answer would also lead you to the required result but you do not need to go back to the beggining, all you have to do is revert the changes on your `app/config/app.php` file and run the update.

hope that helps.

Comment: The **Note** was most helpful. I was pushing Dev to QA and this included the `/app/config/app.php` file changes.  All I did was comment out the two lines in the `app.php` config, ran update and then uncommented the lines.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad it was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. SSL is necessary for composer update and now all works fine. 
So I checked the php ini and set ssl on.

Comment: if you dont like to use SSL, you can use `php composer.phar update --prefer-source`

Answer (score 0):

I just got this same error and being totally new at Laravel I decided to step back, here is what I did to resolve it.

1. removed the entries I added to my composer.json and app.php (I think app.php was the issue)
2. run composer update (yep worked this time)
3. added "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*" to my composer.json
4. run composer update (sentry was installed)
5. added 'Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider' and 'Sentry' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry' to my app.php
6. run composer update (still works)

When I originally installed Sentry I added the 'Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider' to the app.php before running the update and I think this was the issue. ( [install instructions](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2/installation/laravel-4) )

Comment: Sometimes you need to run a php artisan clear-compiled. 
To install recaptcha for laravel this was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For Sentry 3, change the service provider in app/config/app.php to:

```
'Cartalyst\Sentry\Laravel\SentryServiceProvider',
```